# Using Centos v7 for Setup a New Cluster

Tags: hadoop

I want to setup a cluster of Hadoop. Is there any problem if i use Centos v7 for operating system?
I already use Centos 6.5 and in this setup i want to use the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I test it my self and the result was this version is not stable i got a lot of crashes and randomly reboot  in cluster so i back to v6.5 .